# Used dd on a pen drive (wrote Arch to it with Rufus) and now it's invisible

Tags: usb-drive, dd

I ran `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc count=2048` on the pen drive.

I can see the pen drive in the `lsusb` output, and `dmesg` says that it is 8 GB in size, but when I use, say, `cfdisk`, it says that there is 1 MB of free space. (I think that corresponds to some kind of EFI partition that Rufus made.)

There is only a `/dev/sdc` device corresponding to the pen drive.

Please tell me if there is any output you'd like to see.

Update: I ran `dd` again, but without the `count` option, and the drive now shows up as being 2 GB in size (and `dd` threw a "no space left" error). I tried writing a partition table to it with `cfdisk`. It seemingly worked, but there still is no corresponding `/dev/sdc1`.

I then used `mkfs.vfat` on it, and it now shows up as `7.5 GB Removable Media` in Dolphin. But `cfdisk` now says that it is just 2 GB of free space. I can now create files on the pen drive, but will this die suddenly? I want to do a Windows installation using it.

Also, there is now a bunch of "loop devices" in Dolphin. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the misinterpretation of blocksize in different environments. So, you can set it yourself.

You can try

```
dd if=/"file" of=/"out file" bs=2048
```